# How to show different app icon in jump start list & taskbar for different themes?

Tags: uwp, icons, themes, uwp-xaml, appicon

I am developing an UWP app.  The app icon in jump start list is changed when I upgraded to version 20H2 from version 2004. In 2004, the jump start list app icon was shown from targetsize icon. But in 20H2 it seems like the icon is showing from unplated targetsize. Here is an example for Penup app:

[image]

[image]

I want to show app icon for light and dark theme with the following requirements:

1. Different app icon for light and dark theme.
2. The icons in jump start list and taskbar have to be same for a specific theme in all OS versions.

How can I achieve this in windows 10 OS version [from 1803 ~ 20H2]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to show app icon for light and dark theme with the following requirements:Different app icon for light and dark theme.
> The icons in jump start list and taskbar have to be same for a specific theme in all OS versions.
> How can I achieve this in windows 10 OS version [from 1803 ~ 20H2]?

The app's icon background will be same as the OS them color, but it could not be changed to another within version 2004. But for new version 2004h2, it removes the solid color backplates behind the logos.

> Theme-aware tiles in Start – The redesigned Start menu has a more streamlined design that removes the solid color backplates behind the logos in the apps list, and applies a uniform, partially transparent background to the tiles. This design creates a beautiful stage for your icons, especially the Fluent Design icons for Office and Microsoft Edge, as well as the redesigned icons for built-in apps like Calculator, Mail, and Calendar.

For more please refer this [release note](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/what-s-new-for-it-pros-in-windows-10-version-20h2/ba-p/1800132).

Comment: So it is not possible to have different icons in different OS versions, but I need separate builds made, uploaded and released for different OS versions to not brake icon design on older Windows 10 versions + Mobile, but adopt to the new design?